# Rebind error - EventBus cannot be abstract?

Tags: gwt, gwt-platform

My application is throwing this error after I have migrated from GWTP 0.6 to 0.7 and using GWT 2.4.0:

```
[ERROR] Errors in 'generated://3764751F8FC990F2E5309A61EC6876AD/com/mygwtapp/client/gin/ClientGinjectorImpl.java'
      [ERROR] Line 1015:  Rebind result 'com.google.gwt.event.shared.EventBus' cannot be abstract
```

Although I have made sure that the GWTP dependencies in Maven is version 0.7 jars as well as those in the WEB-INF/lib folder

Also I have changed all reference to `EventBus` in the code:

From:

```
import com.google.gwt.event.shared.EventBus;
```

To:

```
import com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.EventBus;
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you don't have `gwtp-all-0.6.jar` in your classpath /dependencies anymore. Also make sure you replaced **ALL** references to `com.google.gwt.event.shared.EventBus` and finally check that [issue](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/issues/detail?id=397).